# Laravel 8 - Bootstap ui does not install

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, bootstrap-ui

In my Laravel 8 application, after installing laravel ui, when I try to run 'php artisan ui bootstrap' I get the following error:

> In Bootstrap.php line 70:
> copy(C:\xampp\htdocs\netlytics\resources\js/bootstrap.js): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have run composer update successfully.
I have `laravel/ui` version 3.2.0. I am running Laravel 8.40.0 with PHP 8.0.3.

The site is an old site that I upgraded from Laravel 5.3 and PHP 5.6.

The pre-processing was being done using gulp with a gulpfile.js to configure the mix conversions.
With Laravel 8 I know I need to update my pre-processing to use webpack.mix.js, but so far can't get there.

There is supposed to be a `resources/app/bootstrap.js` file but it is not showing up and I do not know what it should look like if I wanted to put it there.

Any ideas how to get this installed correctly?

Comment: Did you do all of these steps right?   1. composer require laravel/ui    2. php artisan ui bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I poked around and finally discovered that I needed to install jQuery and jQuery-ui as well as popper.js. I installed those  and again got the same error, but this time I just created a `resources/app/bootstrap.js` file and when I ran `php artisan ui bootstrap`, again, it ran successfully and populated the bootstrap.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Here solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393896/15391779

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist laravel-bootstrap
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm run dev
```