# How to install bootstrap in laravel 8

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-8

All of the info I can find online says that you should install bootstrap by running `composer require laravel/ui` and then `php artisan ui boostrap`. However, in Laravel 8, `laravel/ui` is deprecated. Is there a new/better way of installing bootstrap?

Comment: [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) is the package that is closest to Laravel UI in terms of the backend, however, it's built with TailwindCSS. One option might be to use `Breeze`, install Bootstrap yourself and then copy over the blade files from the `UI`. I'm not 100% sure if this would work without a little tweaking though.

Comment: YES, laravel/ui is deprecated, look at https://github.com/laravel/ui first note in readme ! Breeze/tailwind…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72007507/7186739

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can install bootstrap manually and compile sass.

First, add it to npm with compilers:

```
npm install bootstrap
npm install sass
npm install sass-loader
```

Second, create (if not created) resources/sass/app.scss and add this:

```
@import '~bootstrap';
```

Third, add compilation in webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

Than, compile it with **npm run dev** - you see compiled file public/css/app.css

Now you can use it in templates with asset:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there any documentation where you find this ? I am a beginner in Laravel and I'd like to see details cause this is a bit magic for me haha. I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: it's works thanks

Comment: it's doesn't work with me. getting error " mix: not found", when I run npm run dev

Comment: I think this is because u have laravel 9 with vite. U can install laravel mix or try to google laravel vite bootsrap

Comment: i did fixed using "npm install laravel-mix@latest" command

Answer (score 15):

The way I do it is similar to what you mention, even in Laravel 8.
So I believe you are on the right path.

You can create a new Laravel project using this comand

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist laravel-bootstrap
```

after, in laravel folder run

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

If you just want to add bootstrap to an existing project, just run:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install
npm run dev
```

And if you need Auth

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

Comment: this does not work in Laravel 8x. it throws the error php artisan ui bootstrap

Comment: @KennedyOwusu First run composer require laravel/ui

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1:** Install bootstrap manually

---

1). Download bootstrap's source files from bootstrap website: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/

See this screenshot to download
[image]

2). Rename downloaded bootstrap folder and add it into the Public folder
[image]

3). Load Bootstrap files in your file/view

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="{{asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
       
    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="{{asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Bootstrap btn</button>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Solution 2:** Install bootstrap with package manager

---

**Create Laravel Project**

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist laravel-bootstrap
```

**Select Project Folder**

```
cd laravel-bootstrap
```

**Install Bootstrap in Laravel**

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

**Install Bootstrap Packages**

```
npm -v
```

**Finally, install the bootstrap package and the related frontend dependencies such as jquery**

```
npm install
```

**Compile Assets**

For SCSS: Open resources/sass folder app.scss file and add the following lines

```
@import 'variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

For CSS: Open resources/css folder app.css file and add the following lines

```
@import 'variables';
@import '~bootstrap/css/bootstrap';
```

**Run the below command for asset compilation**

```
for development: npm run dev
for production: npm run production
```

**Automate SASS or CSS and JS Changes**

If you are lazy and don’t want to run the npm run dev command every time you make changes in SASS/CSS and JS file, you should use the following command.

```
npm run watch
```

After compile see this status in terminal

[image]

**Finally, load css and js files in your blade template**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tutorial made by Positronx.io</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

### `composer require laravel/ui` 
`php artisan ui bootstrap` 
`npm install` 
`npm run dev`

If you didn't see Laravel Mix compiled successfully, follow this Mix documentation page "https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/installation"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32214403)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10

Laravel v9.17.0

PHP v8.1.6

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel <project>
cd <project>
composer req laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install bootstrap
npm install sass
npm install sass-loader
npm install && npm run dev
```

Comment: If you would like to use Fortify for Auth, MFA and other Auth functionality, for step 4 simply do `php artisan ui bootstrap`. *Note* you would need to create all required views per the documentation [docs] (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#authentication)

Answer (score 0):

`composer req laravel/ui:*` will resolve the following problem

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, 4.x-dev].
    - laravel/ui[v4.0.0, ..., 4.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^9.21 -> found illuminate/console[v9.21.0, ..., 9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

mentioned  problem will be occured when you have update the laravel and composer into latest version and you are tring to install a previous version there for you have to put following command **in order to fetch supported version of package**

```
composer req laravel/ui:*
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install
npm install resolve-url-loader@^5.0.0 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
npm install sass-loader@^12.1.0 sass resolve-url-loader@^5.0.0 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
npm run dev
```